# Override bootstrap4 variables without editing source

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, npm, sass, bootstrap-4

I've seen a few articles suggesting that I have to edit _custom.scss file and recompile bootstrap. However, I am installing bootstrap4 via npm. Thus, it would be a really bad practice to alter the contents of bootstrap in node_modules.

To be precise, I'm developing Angular4 app and using Angular CLI.

Comment: why can't you just add the css to your own like `core.css` to overwrite, it is a common thing to do

Answer (score 0):

Yes, don't touch the Bootstrap files. Also, don't override the variable at the CSS level, this creates extra code, plus you'd be getting the browser to do extra work.

You want to be overriding the variable at the Sass level, so that Bootstrap's variable gets altered as it's getting converted from Sass to CSS, that way you don't get two rules competing and you're not tied to either load order or specificity wars.

The easiest way to override a Bootstrap variable is to create your own scss file, let’s call it main.scss. Then from here you call your custom variables file variables.scss and then the bootstrap core. So your main.scss file, might look like this;

```
@import "path-to-npm/bootstrap";
@import "path-to-your-repo/variables";
```

And because the good people at Bootstrap don’t always use default flag on their variables, the order in which these files are called matters. So your variables.scss needs to be called last, and might contain something like this;

```
@dropdown-bg: hotpink;
```

You can then set up a Sass watch task, to watch for changes to your main.scss file and convert your variables and the Bootstrap library at the same time and in to one CSS file.